# Least absolute deviation fitting in Matlab

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

I have been using `fittype` function in Matlab for creating a custom fit. The default `fitoptions` involves least squares as fitting criteria. However, I would like to have a least absolute deviation as the criteria.

I have looked up online regarding this, but could not find a built-in matlab solution. Can someone help me how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is somewhat non-intuitive, as you must have set the method to `LinearLeastSquares` or `NonlinearLeastSquares` to access the setting, but if you set in `fitoptions` the robust fitting `'Robust','LAR'` it should do what you want (despite the method being set as a least squares!)

LAR stands for least absolute residual and is just another name for least absolute deviation.